# Testing Class Methods with OCMock

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock

Based on the documentation of OCMock, it should be possible to test class methods, but I may be misunderstanding what is and isn't possible with OCMock. Take the following example method I wish to test:

```
- (void)methodToTest {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}
```

I'd like to test that `dismiss` is called on `SVProgressHUD`. I currently use the following test, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
- (void)testMethodToTest {
    // Create Mock Progress HUD
    id mockProgressHUD = OCMClassMock([SVProgressHUD class]);

    // Configure Mock Progress HUD
    OCMStub(ClassMethod([mockProgressHUD dismiss]));

    // Invoke Method to Test
    [object methodToTest];

    OCMVerify([mockProgressHUD dismiss]);
}
```

Is it possible with OCMock to test whether `dismiss` is called on `SVProgressHUD`?

Answer (score 0):

Your test passes for me. Perhaps it's something subtle in your implementation? What is `object`? Here's my simplified version:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
+ (void)dismiss;
@end

@implementation Foo
+ (void)dismiss
{
    NSLog(@"Dismiss!");
}
@end

@interface Bar : NSObject
- (void)methodToTest;
@end

@implementation Bar
- (void)methodToTest
{
    [Foo dismiss];
}
@end

- (void)testClassMock
{
    Bar *bar = [Bar new];

    id mockFoo = OCMClassMock([Foo class]);
    OCMStub(ClassMethod([mockFoo dismiss]));

    [bar methodToTest];

    OCMVerify([mockFoo dismiss]);
}
```

Comment: `object` is a partially mocked object, but that shouldn't affect the test. If I add a breakpoint in the method that's being tested, `dismiss` is called on the `SVProgressHUD`, OCMock doesn't pick this up for some reason.

Comment: Can you add how you are creating `object` to the question? There's nothing weird about SVProgressHUD -- it should be allowing the mock.